# Windows batch script fails when calling more than 1 .vbs scripts

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I have a batch file that sets 4 different parameters and attempts to call a .vbs script for every parameter. The first call works just fine, but the second call ( and every other afterwards) throws an exception:
VBScript runtime error: Subscript out of range

I have tried renaming the script and copying it, so that it is a new script, but even then, the 2nd call fails.

```
for /F %%a in ('dir ***** /B /S') do    set fileName=%%~fa 
for /F %%a in ('dir ****** /B /S') do set fileName2=%%~fa  
goto : new

:new
set hostName=%1
set portNumber=%2
set majorVersion=%3
set instance=%4

call ******.vbs %hostName% %portNumber% %majorVersion% %fileName%%instance% 
call ******.vbs %hostName% %portNumber% %majorVersion% %fileName4%%instance%
```

Where ****** is the directory, where the script and files are located.

Comment: You reference fileName4 and not fileName2?

Answer (score 0):

Give this a crack:

```
cscript /nologo ******.vbs %hostName% %portNumber% %majorVersion% %fileName%%instance% 
cscript /nologo ******.vbs %hostName% %portNumber% %majorVersion% %fileName4%%instance%
```

Your path\filenames might also contain spaces and poison characters, which don't look to be handled correctly.  You may need to double quote them.

```
"%fileName%%instance%"
"%fileName4%%instance%"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cscript "Test.vbs" "param1-name" "param2-name" "param3-name"
```

or

```
cscript ******.vbs "%hostName%" "%portNumber%" "%majorVersion%" "%fileName%%instance%"
```

or

```
"Test.vbs" "param1-name" "param2-name" "param3-name"
```

And if you need some delay in between the scripts execution, use the below:

```
TIMEOUT /T 3
```

Try the way you like.Enjoy!